# Make header push down instead of up on second line

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

Consider this document with a long header:

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\rohead{This is a really long header, it's so long it even needs a second line. No really, it does need a second line!}
\lehead{This is a short line for comparison.}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-24]
\end{document}
```

The shorter header on even pages demonstrates the contrast with the long header on the odd pages.

The expected behaviour would be that the first line of the odd page header sits at the same height as the even page header.
It should thus reduce the height of the text area, but instead, the text area remains in place and the header moves up towards the top edge of the page.

How can I get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\parbox`, but you have to take care that the header does not overlap the text area:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\rohead{%
  \parbox[t][\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{\raggedleft%
    This is a really long header, it's so long it even needs a second line.
    No really, it does need a second line!%
  }%
}

\lehead{This is a short line for comparison.}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-24]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution works without having to insert a manual break and without loading an additional package.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to provide a manual line break, then this stack might work:

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\rohead{\smash{\Longunderstack[r]{This is a really long header, it's so long 
  it even needs a second line. No really, it does\\need a second line!}}}
\lehead{This is a short line for comparison.}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-24]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. The text in the header will actually come from the \title (or rather: titling's \thetitle) command and will change multiple times throughout the document, so manually breaking lines is not preferred (but I will try if your solution works, of course). Maybe I can get away with your solution by breaking lines once between \thetitle and \thesubtitle (if titling provides such a command, I haven't checked). This would be inconvenient though, because a subtitle is not present in all cases.

Comment: @Philipp One possibility that might work is to change the stackEOL from \\ to `\empty`, since the latter will have no ill effects when typset in a title or toc.  Thus, `\setstackEOL{\empty}
\rohead{\smash{\Longunderstack[r]{This is a really long header, it's so long it even needs a second line. No really, it does \empty need a second line!}}}`